# How to write logs to EventLog by ILogger<T> in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ilogger

I follow this document [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1), try to write log to Windows EventLog.

first, I create Source and Log in Windows Event Log:

```
if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MyTestSource"))
{
    EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyTestSource", "MyTestLog");
    return;
}
```

and it's created.

then, I configured logging in CreateHostBuilder from Program.cs of my ASP.NET Core app (core 3.0):

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings
            {
                SourceName = "MyTestSource",
                LogName = "MyTestLog"
            });
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

I think that's all. Then I use logger in my controller:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ServerController : ControllerBase
{
    ILogger<ServerController> _logger = null;
    public ServerController(ILogger<ServerController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetServerInfo")]
    public string GetServerInfo()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("GetServerInfo Called");
        return "Hello I'm Server";
    }
}
```

but there's nothing in MyTestLog in Windows EventLog. Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 12):

You can go for a configuration only approach, leaving your existing `CreateHostBuilder` code as-is.

As mentioned in the document you linked, under the [Windows Eventlog section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#windows-eventlog), the `EventLogProvider` defaults to the warning level when not explicitly configured:

> Unlike the other providers, the EventLog provider does not inherit the
> default non-provider settings.
> If EventLog log settings aren't
> specified, they default to LogLevel.Warning.

To lower this logging level to  `Information`, you have to foresee an explicit entry for the `EventLog` provider in the `Logging` section of your `appsettings.{Environment}.json` file.

E.g.: `appsettings.Development.json`:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "System": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information"
        },
        "EventLog": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Information"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's caused by `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)`, which executes:

```
.ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder => {
    loggingBuilder.AddFilter<EventLogLoggerProvider>((Func<LogLevel, bool>) (level=>level>=LogLevel.Warning));
}
```

under the hood. Warning is 1 level higher than Information, so...

As a solution, you can create fresh `HostBuilder` using `new HostBuilder()` and configure it from scratch or override that behavior by calling `.ConfigureLogging` after creating default host builder.

Answer (score 2):

Try bumping up your logging to `_logger.LogError("GetServerInfo Called"")` and see if it works. If it does, then you will have to set up your log filtering

Comment: hi Paul, LogError can write into Windows EventLog, but LogInformation not work, how to make it work?