# Logging LogLevel-Information not showing in Windows event log

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, event-log

I ran into some problems with logging **Information** Logs to Windows event log.
Starting from a blank ASP.NET Core-Web-API .Net 5

I edited the following to Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddEventLog(eventLogSettings =>
            {
                eventLogSettings.SourceName = "MyTestLog";
            });

        });
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

and wrote some sample logs into a Controler

```
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    _logger.LogCritical("Critical Log");
    _logger.LogError("Error Log");
    _logger.LogWarning("Warning Log");
    _logger.LogInformation("Info Log");
    _logger.LogDebug("Debug Log");
    _logger.LogTrace("Trace Log");
    ...
}
```

If I Run it, it shows logs for Critical - Error - Warning - Information in Console. Matching what is configured in AppSettings.
appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

In Windows event log it only shows Critical, Error and Warning -Logs, not caring for my appsettings whatsoever.
I'm sure this is an easy configuration problem, but i don't find any documentation for this.

How do I get Logs with Loglevel-Information in Windows event log ?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65399284/9200675)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#windows-eventlog), you could find the ASP.NET Core provide the event logging feature. Unlike the other providers, the EventLog provider does not inherit the default non-provider settings.

If EventLog log settings aren't specified, they default to `LogLevel.Warning`.

To log events lower than `LogLevel.Warning`, explicitly set the log level. The following example sets the Event Log default log level to `LogLevel.Information`:

```json
"Logging": {
  "EventLog": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I put this Logging setup in my appsettings.json: "Logging": {
  "EventLog": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
} But the application would not log the Information for the Controller activity. When I deleted appSettings.json alltogether, it would log everything , like this: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5232/api/test - -
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'WebAPIBareboneDotNet6.Controllers .....